# How to align text in bottom of label

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've got problems to get text in the label to the bottom of the label.

I'm animating a falling text, the label does "seem" to fall as it should, but the text stays on top, it's not following the label downwards. Please check this jsfiddle out, press the button to see the problem. I have tried many different ways without coming up with a working solution.

http://jsfiddle.net/kaze72/jQ6Ua/

```
.uppgifter
{
    vertical-align: text-bottom;
}
```

Seems not to help!

Comment: but you are not making the label fall. you are simply increasing its height?? is that you really want??

Comment: Yes, in that way, I can have a "cool" background leaving a trace!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
.uppgifter
{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LeDBB/1/)

*Updated jsFiddle so that `.uppgifter`'s height in `animate` method matches `#spelplan`'s height.*

Comment: Thanks, works great! Btw, do you know if it's possible to changes (one of) the label horizontal alignment? I've tried left: 50px and margin-left 50px without luck.

Comment: You try `padding: 0 50px;`. That will put 50px from both sides of labels. See here http://jsfiddle.net/ugSVG/

Answer (score 0):

```
.uppgifter
{

    padding: 580px 0 1px 230px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just animate the padding-top:

```
$("#the_button").click(function () {
    $(".uppgifter").animate({
        'padding-top':"500px"
    }, 4000, "linear", function() {});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#the_button").click(function () {
        $(".uppgifter").animate({ 
            "height":"100px","padding-top":"500px"}, 
            4000, "linear", function() {});
    });
});
```

or just a suggestion, take a look at this :):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#the_button").click(function () {
        $(".uppgifter").animate({ 
            "top":"500px"}, 4000, "linear", function() {});
    });
});
```

combined with

```
.uppgifter
    {
        vertical-align: text-bottom;
        position:relative;
        background-color: yellow;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    * 
    {
        font-family: cursive;
    }

    .panel
    {
        position:relative;
        border: 1px solid;
    }

    #spelplan
    {
        height: 600px;
    }

    .uppgifter
    {
        position:absolute;
        vertical-align: text-bottom;
bottom:0;

        background-color: yellow;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I simply added two transparent divs set with a 90% height that force the text down as the label height changes.

http://jsfiddle.net/jQ6Ua/15/

```
#div
{
height:90%;
width:200%
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To vertically align a text in a container, [multiple techniques](http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/vertical-centering/) can be used. However, most of them have additional script calculation at runtime (if the height of the text container is changing) which can mess with the business logic.

A hack can be used in your particular situation.
You can add an image container with empty src inside your text container with **100% height** and **0 width** set by css.

```
<label id="uppgift" class="uppgifter" style="display:inline-block;"><img scr=""/>Abc</label>
<label id="uppgift2" class="uppgifter" style="display:inline-block;"><img scr=""/>123</label>

//and css
.uppgifter img{
    height:100%;
    width:0;
}
```

**[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/jQ6Ua/12/)**

This way you would not have to write logic for additional added layers.